# Python: How to safely close a file while it is keep reading/writing?

Tags: python

Python: How to safely close a file while it is keep reading/writing?

I keep seeing the error `ValueError('I/O operation on closed file',)`.

How to avoid it?

I'm actually working with software UI stuff. When the close button is clicked,
I have to force close the file and quit app, the key logic is as below:

```
file = openfile("XXXX", 'r')
while True:
    line = file.readline()
    //process line
```

When the close button is clicked:

```
def close_file():
    file.close()
```

Many thanks

Comment: Don't close the file until you're done using it.

Comment: but the requirement is I have to force quit it :(

Comment: You need to clarify the question. Explain what you're trying to do, show the code, and explain what the problem is with it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Stop the writing operations, revert them and then close the file?

Comment: ya but how to stop the writing operation...

Comment: Threading or multiprocessing is allowed to be used if anyone can fix it by using them:)

Comment: use `while running:` and set `running = False` to stop loop.

Comment: ya set running works!

Answer (score 0):

```
file = openfile("XXXX", 'r')
while True:
    if the close button is clicked:
        break
    line = file.readline()
    //process line
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

use while running: and set running = False to stop loop.